# Removing data from list pointed to by a pointer in C

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list, nodes

I have been trying for a while to figure out a recursive way to remove a node (from anywhere in a linked list) without leaving any memory leaks.

Is this possible??

Here is my non-recursive way that does not work:

```
    int removeItem(struct ListNode** headRef, int data)
    {
    struct ListNode* temp = *headRef; // store original head
    int val = data;
    while (temp->next != NULL)
    {
    if (temp->next->data != val)
    {
    temp = temp->next;
    }
    else if (temp->next->data == val)
    {
    temp = temp->next;
    free(temp);
    return 1;
  }
  else
  {
  return 0;
   }
 }
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Lets look at your code, you might be close.

Comment: Make the previous entry point to the next entry and then free the memory associated with the removed entry.

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by "a recursive way" as removing a node from a list is just a single step

Comment: I would like to use recursion to simplify the function but I can't wrap my brain around it...

Answer (score 1):

I'm honestly not sure I followed the question, but is *this* what you're trying to do?

```
int removeItem(struct ListNode** headRef, int data)
{
    if (!*headRef)
        return 0;

    if ((*headRef)->data != data)
        return removeItem(&(*headRef)->next, data);

    // found it. drop it out.
    struct ListNode *tmp = *headRef;
    *headRef = tmp->next;
    free(tmp);
    return 1;
}
```

And if it is, *don't*. It is better to do this task via iteration (you may find it a *little* harder to understand, but I can't imagine why, if you understand the recursive solution):

```
int removeItem(struct ListNode** headRef, int data)
{
    while (*headRef && (*headRef)->data != data)
        headRef = &(*headRef)->next;

    if (*headRef)
    {
        struct ListNode *tmp = *headRef;
        *headRef = tmp->next;
        free(tmp);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**How they work**

Both of these functions work by using `headRef` to always hold the address **of the pointer** that references the node we're testing.

Initially `headRef` contains the address of the `head` pointer for the list. Each time we need to move to the next node we load the the address of the pointer referring to that node in `headRef`. When we finally find the node we seek, the address of the pointer that references it is in `headRef` (may be the original `head` pointer, or some `next` pointer somewhere in the list; which one really doesn't matter).

The difference between the two functions is straight-forward. In the first, we use recursion to pass the address of the next pointer we're going to test to the recursed call. In the second, we just use an iterative loop. Either way, `headRef` always holds the address of the pointer that is pointing to the node we're testing. If we find a winner (loser, in this case), note that *both* functions do the *identical operation*: save the value in `*headRef` (its our pointer were freeing), populate `*headRef` with the value of the current-node's `next`, then delete the old node. Drawing it on paper will help a ton (my ascii art *sucks*; sry).

Comment: Hmmm...okay, yeah I'm not sure I understand what is happening there. Here is the description of what the function is supposed to do: Remove data from list pointed to by headRef, changing head if necessary.
 * Make no assumptions as to whether the list is sorted.
 * Memory for removed node should be freed.
 * Return 1 if data was present, 0 if not found.

Comment: @user3366369 yup, both of the above do that. You should note the assignment does *not* include removing *all* elements of a specified value. Were that the case both of these would be different (but not by much). I'll hint you up how they work; they use `headRef` as a local variable to walk from one node to the next using the pointers *in* those nodes (not just the addresses those pointers contain) to do so. The same way the `headRef` var originally holds the address of the head pointer, we also use it to hold the addresses of `next` pointers in the linked nodes.

Comment: How would I add a check to see if the data being put in is actually in the list at all?

Comment: This does that too. It returns 1 if the data *was* in the list, zero if it wasn't. Or do you mean just something that walks the list without freeing and looking for some data value, returning zero or non-zero if it is-not or is found respectively?

Comment: No that's what I meant, thank for the clarification! I must be doing something else weird because I am still getting the wrong output and it is saying that it is not finding certain numbers in the list even though they are actually there...

Comment: You may want to double check that with a print-function. I can test this if you want, but it will take a minute. They should both work correctly (dunno which one you were testing). And of course, make **sure** your list is terminated with NULL in the last `next`.

Comment: Well the test case I am using is from my instructor so I know there isn't anything wrong in there...and everything seems to work ok up until here and then it goes wonky so I am not sure what to think...

Comment: [**See it live**](https://ideone.com/kYVwB6). The linked sample actually builds the list sorted just so its easier to search for values that were deleted. It has no effect on the actual algorithm for removing items. Are you *sure* the requirement doesn't say to remove *all* nodes that hold the specified value, not just the *first* node found ? it would obviously make a difference. And of course, there is always the chance you're not building the list quite correctly (possibly).

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I really don't know why this isn't working, my list is built correctly so I have no clue what it would be...

Comment: Oh man I got it working up until that point...now I have some other funky problems but at least I got past that bug! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

A recursive method would require an additional arguments.  Initially, it would be called like this:

```
...
rc=removeItem(&headRef, NULL, NULL, 42);
...
```

The recursive version of the function might be implemented like this:

```
int removeItem(
      struct ListNode **headRef,
      struct ListNode  *parentNode,
      struct ListNode  *currentNode,
      int data
      )
   {
```

If this is the first call to this function, set currentNode to the list's head.

```
   if(NULL == currentNode)
      currentNode=*headRef;
```

Is this the node to delete?

```
   if(currentNode->data == data)
      {
```

Is this the head node?

```
      if(currentNode == *headRef)
```

If it is the head, modify the headRef to point to the node beyond the current node.

```
         *headRef = currentNode->next;
      else
```

Otherwise, modify the parent node to skip the currentNode, and point to the next node.

```
         parentNode->next = currentNode->next;
```

The currentNode can now be safely freed.

```
      free(currentNode);
```

Done.

```
      return(1);
      }
```

If the currentNode isn't the one we are looking for, recurse back into this function with the next node. (Unless we have reached the end of the list).

```
return(
   currentNode->next 
      ? removeItem(headRef, currentNode, currentNode->next, data)
      : 0
   );
}
```

=================================================================

Perhaps it could be implemented this way (iteritive, not recursive):

```
int removeItem(
      struct ListNode **headRef, 
      int data
      )
   {
   struct ListNode *currentNode = *headRef; // Copy the address of headref. 
   struct ListNode *parentNode = NULL;
```

Iterate through all list nodes.

```
   while(currentNode)
      {
```

Is this the one?

```
      if(currentNode->data == data)
         {
```

Yes, this is a match.

The first step in deleting this node is to unlink it from the list.  The method of unlinking depends on if this is the head node, or a later sibling node.

Is this the head (or first) node?

```
         if(NULL == parentNode)
```

If it is the head node, then the headRef must be adjusted to point to the next (or second) node.

```
            *headRef = currentNode->next;
         else
```

Ok, it's not the head node, it is a later sibling. to unlink this node, the parent of this node must be modified to point beyond the current node.

```
            parentNode->next = currentNode->next;
```

Now that the currentNode is unlinked from the list, it can be safely freed.

```
         free(currentNode);
         return 1;
         }
```

Remember this node to be the parent of the next node.

```
      parentNode=currentNode;
```

Move on to the next node in the list.

```
      currentNode = currentNode->next;
      }

    return 0;
    }
```